# How do I say group conformity?

Tags: meaning, words

I want to use the word group conformity in the following sentence. The Japanese value group conformity in society. 集団準拠［適合］was listed in EOW/ALT but I want to know if there is a difference between them. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not incorrect, but they look and sound very "translated" and overly technical.

The far more common (like a few hundred times as common) terms would be:

> 「協調性{きょうちょうせい}」 and 「集団行動{しゅうだんこうどう}」

Answer (score 0):

- 適合 is a word which means something fits to a size or within the rules. Used widely in conversation.
- 準拠 is a formal word for conformity. Often preferred in written documents.